# why NaN number?

Tags: c#, nan, delta

I am trying to calculate the delta of a number using a formula of bhaskara and delta but it is giving NaN in the message box

```
//Variables declaration
int a = 800, b = 500, c = 350;
double delta, a1, a2;

//Formulas
delta = (b*b) - (4*a*c);
a1 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
a2 = (-b - Math.Sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);

//Output
MessageBox.Show(a1.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(a2.ToString());
```

[image]

Comment: Because it can't take square root of negative number. BTW, regarding the title, NaN = "Not a Number".

Comment: a negative will return NaN, from the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sqrt?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 2):

The value of `delta` is -870000.
That's not a value you can take the square root of (and get a [real number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) anyway).

From the [Math.Sqrt docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sqrt?view=netframework-4.8):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As Broots said `Math.sqrt` of negative number will return NaN. There is a [Complex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.complex?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) struct that should do what you need:

```
Complex c = Complex.Sqrt(-25); // has a value of approximately 0 + 5i
```